# The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: bash, makefile, cmake, compiler-errors, virtualization

I would like to virtualize Android on my jetson nano using qemu + kvm + virglrenderer and I found these tutorials to accomplish the task :

this :

https://www.collabora.com/.../building-android-for-qemu.../

and this :

https://www.collabora.com/.../02/12/virtualizing-gpu-access/

so. on Ubuntu 20.10 I have added this script to the .bashrc file and I did : source ~/.bashrc

```
function add_export_env {
  local VAR="$1"
  shift
  local VAL=$(eval echo "\$$VAR")
  if [ "$VAL" ]; then
    VAL=$(concatenate_colon "$@" "$VAL");
  else
    VAL=$(concatenate_colon "$@");
  fi
  eval "export $VAR=\"$VAL\""
}
function prefix_setup {
  local PREFIX="$1"
  add_export_env PATH "$PREFIX/bin"
  add_export_env LD_LIBRARY_PATH "$PREFIX/lib"
  add_export_env PKG_CONFIG_PATH "$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/" "$PREFIX/share/pkgconfig/"
  add_export_env MANPATH "$PREFIX/share/man"
  export ACLOCAL_PATH="$PREFIX/share/aclocal"
  mkdir -p "$ACLOCAL_PATH"
  export ACLOCAL="aclocal -I $ACLOCAL_PATH"
}
function projectshell {
  case "$1" in
    virgl | virglrenderer)
        export ALT_LOCAL="/opt/local/virgl"
        mkdir -p "$ALT_LOCAL"
        prefix_setup "$ALT_LOCAL"
        ;;
  esac
}
```

and I have also installed these packages :

```
sudo apt install autoconf gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu libaio-dev libbluetooth-dev libbrlapi-dev libbz2-dev libcap-dev libcap-ng-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libepoxy-dev libfdt-dev libgbm-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libibverbs-dev libjpeg8-dev liblzo2-dev libncurses5-dev libnuma-dev librbd-dev librdmacm-dev libsasl2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsdl2-dev libseccomp-dev libsnappy-dev libssh2-1-dev libtool libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev libvde-dev libvdeplug-dev libvte-2.90-dev libxen-dev valgrind xfslibs-dev xutils-dev zlib1g-dev
```

and configured these paths :

```
export PROJECT_PATH="/opt/qemu_android"
export VIRGLRENDERER_PATH="${PROJECT_PATH}/virglrenderer"
export QEMU_PATH="${PROJECT_PATH}/qemu" export LINUX_PATH="${PROJECT_PATH}/linux"
export ANDROID_PATH="${PROJECT_PATH}/android"
export ANDROID_TOOLS_PATH="${PROJECT_PATH}/android-tools"
```

then :

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/virglrenderer

root@aorus:/opt/qemu_android/virglrenderer# ls

ci docs   perf-testing  virglrenderer.pc.inconfig.h.meson meson.build   src vtestCOPYING meson_options.txt  tests

root@aorus:/opt/qemu_android/virglrenderer# ./autogen.sh

bash: ./autogen.sh: File or directory not found
```

I don't know how to compile it,since the classic way does not work (mkdir build ; cd build ; cmake ..) it says :

```
CMake Error: The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Comment: CMake is now considered "the classic way"?  How the times they do change... :)

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `ls` and saw the files in your `virgilrenderer` folder there isn't an `./autogen.sh` but there is a `meson.build`

So let's try that.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install meson ninja-build
cd /opt/qemu_android/virglrenderer
meson compile
```

Once Meson is installed, and you are in the directory that the `meson.build` file is, you should be able to just run the `meson compile` command.

[Official Docs for Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/SimpleStart.html)

Comment: root@ziomario-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/opt/qemu_android/virglrenderer# meson compile
ERROR: Current directory is not a meson build directory: `/opt/qemu_android/virglrenderer`.
Please specify a valid build dir or change the working directory to it.
It is also possible that the build directory was generated with an old
meson version. Please regenerate it in this case.

Comment: Try `meson configure` then `meson compile`

Comment: nothing : give a look what happens : https://pastebin.com/Fpau8AGY

Comment: `mkdir -p build && rm -rf build/* && meson build && ninja-build -C build`

Give this a shot, it will make a new directory for the build if it doesn't already exist, and then it will remove it recursive/force if it does exist and then it will run the meson build, and the ninja build. 

Then try `meson compile`

Comment: I'm learning this along with you, so thanks for the patience!

Comment: but not yet. ninja-buid : command not found

Comment: please give a look at this : https://pastebin.com/5dvvKwms

Comment: Shot in the dark but try these? lol

`cd build/default`
`cmake -GNinja ../..`

Comment: I've followed this procedure : https://pastebin.com/1vJ0pgbb ; but Im not sure that it is good,because I don't see any executable...

Comment: Can you paste an `ls` command? See what files ARE in the directory?

Comment: What if you just type `ninja` while in that directory and then do a `ls`? Do we see a file named `something.c`?

Comment: when I write "ninja" in the directory "/home/ziomario/Scrivania/Collabora/libepoxy/build it says : "no work to do". if I do that on the directory "/home/ziomario/Collabora/libepoxy/ it says : ninja: error loading build.ninja: no such file or directory. I don't see c files.

Comment: a lot of c and h files are inside the folder "src"

Comment: this is interesting : https://pastebin.com/hFgP9V7t

Comment: Have you tried just installing it from apt? `sudo apt-get install libvirglrenderer0` Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libvirglrenderer1` Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10